# INTEL XDK - can't increase version number for google play store to load later .apk file

Tags: android, intel-xdk

I'm using the latest version of Intel XDK to create android apps.

I just uploaded an android .apk file to google play (production) and realized it was the earlier verion of the file. However, I now can't update it on the store. It continually gives me this error:

Upload failed
You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1

But I've tried changing the app version # in the project build settings & looked at the .xdk config file, etc.

So I'm stuck with an app that has a bug out there & don't know how to change it.

Any suggestions would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to email Google Play Developer support (in case it's an issue on their end). The last time I contacted them, may be a year or so ago, they responded within 24 hours and resolved my issue pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later versions of the XDK allow it to be set in the Projects tab?  If it's not there, you have to change it manually as you mentioned in the config xml .

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change the internal version code for the playstore, showing users can update. 
You can assign it through the android manifest tag   (posted below as plain text)

> ```
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     package="com.example.native_activity"
>     android:versionCode="1"
>     android:versionName="1.1"
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the information ;)  I'm trying to figure out how to do that using Intel XDK though.  It has a UI for changing the App verision & uses their .xdk config file to generate their custom "intelxdk.config.android.xml" files each time

Comment: It's on the Project tab under "Build Settings" labeled as "App Version Code." This corresponds to the "versionCode" mentioned in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to update the following (found under Build Settings) to fix this issue;

1. App Version
2. App Version Code

Here's the tutorial that helped me fix this issue;
https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/1249/how-to-update-your-app-on-google-play